# After migrating to v5 image resize not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-native-image

**Current Behavior**

In react navigation v4 I used this code and worked just fine. It did adjust my logo image (300x80) to fit perfectly and scale into my 80px header.

Now after migrating to v5 it no longer scale. It's just like the 'resizeMode' stopped working.

[image: Current behavior]

```
const navigationOptions = { headerTitle: <Image style={{height: 45}} resizeMode="contain" source={require('../assets/images/encabezado-1.png')}/>, headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white', shadowColor: 'none', }, headerTitleAlign: 'center', headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: 'normal', fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', }, }
```

**Expected Behavior**

I expect my image to be contained and scaled properly. Like in v4:

[image]

**How to reproduce**

Add an image to headerTitle and try resizeMode.

**Your Environment**

- Android 9

  - @react-navigation/native  5.2.2
  - @react-navigation/stack    5.2.3
  - react-native-gesture-handler  1.6.1
  - react-native-safe-area-context 0.7.3
  - react-native-screens  2.4.0
  - react-native   0.61.5
  - node  12.6.1

Answer (score 1):

resizeMode is still working. you can use in Stack.Screen -> options -> title prop.

code example:

```
<TakeSendStack.Navigator initialRouteName={"TakeSend"}>
      <TakeSendStack.Screen name="TakeSend" options={{ title: <Image style={{height: 45}} source={require('../assets/logo/logo.png')}/> }} component={TakeSend} />
</TakeSendStack.Navigator>
```

[image]

add resizeMode

```
<TakeSendStack.Navigator initialRouteName={"TakeSend"}>
      <TakeSendStack.Screen name="TakeSend" options={{ title: <Image style={{height: 45}} resizeMode="contain" source={require('../assets/logo/logo.png')}/> }} component={TakeSend} />
</TakeSendStack.Navigator>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried what you did but no result:

    <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{title: <Image style={{height: 45}} resizeMode="contain" source={require('../assets/images/encabezado-1.png')}/>}}/>

And I keep having the same behavior.

Comment: Problem on Android. Can you add headerTitleAlign in Stack.Navigator and custom width in Image item? <HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName={"Home"} screenOptions={{headerTitleAlign: 'center'}}> <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{title: <Image style={{height: 45, width: 200}}  source={require('../assets/images/encabezado-1.png')}/>}}/> ... </HomeStack.Navigator>